# How to go to menu when logging in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I went to go and log in but when I got on it it just kept saying loading and it still says that . How do I exit to the main menu?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to exit back to the menu is to quit out of Minecraft, which can be done by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> or going through Task Manager, and restart it.